# Load Fonts into .qss Stylesheet for Qt Applications

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I am using QSS to style my application written in C++.

I would like to be able to load the fonts into the QSS stylesheet, but the documentation is very unclear how to do this.

There is stuff about QML, but nothing about QSS.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontloader.html

Any ideas on how to load into the QSS?

Does something like @import and @fontface from css exist?

I improperly am using the QML imports as I had misread the documentation... But i was hoping something like this would work and the documents on the site are really not supportive of QSS at all.

```
FontLoader { id: QUANTICO; name: Quantico; source: ":/fonts/quantico" }
FontLoader { id: ROBOTO_LIGHT; name: Roboto-Light; source: ":/fonts/roboto_light" }
FontLoader { id: ROBOTO_REGULAR; name: Roboto-Regular; source: ":/fonts/roboto_regular" }

QWidget {
    background: rgb(34,49,70);
    font-family: Roboto-Light;
}
```

I was hoping that this would work like @import in css, but apparently not. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: IMHO; Qt stylesheets suck donkeys kidneys. Don't waste time on them. They are not well implemented, they are not well maintained or supported. Just stay away from them.

Comment: Great @JesperJuhl, can you give me some direction on the best way to do it? Is the QML font loader the recommended approach?

Comment: @AustinWitherow Where do you want to load the sources, from a .qrc, from a url?

Comment: @eyllanesc if you want to look, the current PR is here https://github.com/InterstellarHoldings/InterstellarHoldings/pull/3

It is using .qrc in this project.

Comment: @AustinWitherow  I do not understand you, explain to me what you want to do.

Comment: @eyllanesc in the .qss file I was assuming there would be something like (at)import or (at)fontfamily, but I used the FontLoader there. It did not work as expected (well of course, because it is not QML). I was wondering if there is an alternative INSIDE qss to load fonts? Because how I am doing it in the holdify.qss file is clearly not working. Is there something similar to what I am doing there that DOES work?

Comment: I could show the content or the location of holdify.qss, I can not find it, I also think that it has the ability to create a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for the late response, got busy with some stuff :) I am updating with a sample.